# Functions and for loops

Tags: python, loops

Python newbie here.
I Got an exercise to write a function that receives 2 parameters, the first is a single note string, and the other is the max length(int) of the middle row. (i.e arrow(my_char, max_length)
Basically the function is supposed to return an "arrow formation".
I'm supposed to use a for loop for this.
for ex. the print for print(arrow("*", 5)) is supposed to be:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

What I've done so far:

```
for i in range(1, max_length + 1):
    print (my_char * i)

for i in range(max_length, 1, -1):
    print (my_char * i)
```

I got the formation right, but the formation is not returned and I need to add spaces between the asterisks.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Looking for a general direction to work with, asking for a complete answer won't do me no good

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: Edited in what I tried

Comment: thank you for providing more details, I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: "Got an exercise to write a function..." The code you posted here doesn't have this function you are supposed to write. I think you should start there. Figure out how to define a function that takes two parameters and performs the task that you want. You also need to learn about how to return a value from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your question description and what you did, it appears that to works properly the argument of `print()` in your second for loop must be `my_char*(i-1)` instead of `my_char*i`. Then you can add spaces between asterisks, and tie all into a function taking 2 parameters as follows:

```
def arrow(my_char, max_length):
    for i in range(1, max_length + 1):
        print(" ".join(my_char * i))

    for i in range(max_length, 1, -1):
        print(" ".join(my_char * (i-1)))
```

**Example:** If you take `my_char = "*"` and `max_length = 5`, the function `arrow(my_char, max_length)` will output:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many answers would be like this:

```
def arrow(char, length):
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i):
            print(char + ' ', end='')
        print ()
    for i in range(length,0,-1):
        for j in range(i,0,-1):
            print(char + ' ', end='')
        print ()
```